# Multiple endpoints in ABP framework project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, abp

I have created new solution using abp framework command. It has a HttpApi.Host in port 44342 and angular UI hosted at port 4200. I have two app services in application layer A and be B and hence two endpoints in port 44342. Now I dont want angular application to access B App service and end point. I want to host separately in different port. That B might need all the features like authentication logging and same database but only have separate hosting. How do I achive that in ABP framework.

I thought HttpAPI.Client project for similar purpose I couldnt understand how to do that or configure properly.

Comment: Using different ports won't stop the Angular clients from accessing them. Just add a simple authX layer.

Comment: I am planning to host separately and have network level restriction on second applicaton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is used static proxy generation in .Client project which was unused previously.
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/API/Static-CSharp-API-Clients

after that I created new Web api project, Installed all the ABP packages and managed all the pipelines like in the original .Hosts Project but project dependency only httpapi.client project instead of .httpapi project.

I still have not figured out how to hide that B App service from .httpapi or .host project but I will update once I do.

[UPDATE]
Removing one controller ended up working for me.

```html
services.Configure<AbpAspNetCoreMvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ControllersToRemove.Add(typeof(AbpLanguagesController));
});
```

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/API/Auto-API-Controllers